# update year for all the records in MS access

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have two date/time columns in access `LAST_ORDER_DT` and `SALE_DT`
I want to update the year of all sales `dates(SALE_DT)` to the year of `LAST_ORDER_DT`

I tried the following statement and it threw syntax error.

```
UPDATE ORDERS_TEMP SET YEAR(SALE_DT)=YEAR(LAST_ORDER_DT)
```

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand your question, you might have a `SALE_DT` of `#2011-09-30#` with a `LAST_ORDER_DT` of `#2012-10-10#`, and you want `SALE_DT` changed to `#2012-09-30#`.

If that's the case, you can use the `DateSerial()` function to reconstruct `SALE_DT` from the appropriate year, month, and day values.

```
UPDATE ORDERS_TEMP
SET SALE_DT =
    DateSerial(
        Year(LAST_ORDER_DT),
        Month(SALE_DT),
        Day(SALE_DT)
        );
```

That should work if the time of day is midnight for your `SALE_DT` values.  If the time of day is anything else, you need to add that part in, too.

```
UPDATE ORDERS_TEMP
SET SALE_DT =
    DateSerial(
        Year(LAST_ORDER_DT),
        Month(SALE_DT),
        Day(SALE_DT)
        )
    + TimeValue(SALE_DT);
```

If `SALE_DT` and `LAST_ORDER_DT` can contain Null, you should exclude those rows from the `UPDATE` query:

```
WHERE SALE_DT Is Not Null AND LAST_ORDER_DT Is Not Null
```